# Content not visible in my single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, post

My page posts are not showing in my single.php file.  Here is a link to my page: http://list.thorsteinnhelgason.is/index.php/blog/

and this is the code I use:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="content">
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php 
      endwhile; 
      endif; 
     ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (sorry, ignore my previous comment, didn't notice the `wordpress` tag)

Comment: There isn't enough info here to understand the problem. What is your single.php file? Is it the main file for a plug-in you wrote? Do you initialize it in any way? From the code it looks like a template file, which you need to load, but that depends on where you put it. More details are needed to properly answer the question.

Comment: Something is not setup right. You shouldn't see that 'index.php' in the URL - at least with basic setup.

Comment: And a question: does **the_title();** work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

the single.php will not be the file you want. single.php (for posts) or singualr.php (posts or pages) is for displaying the single post, not a list of posts.

The page that you have linked to, based on the name, is a list of posts (or loop) which based on the wordpress template heirarchy will use index.php, home.php, front-page.php https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

The easiest way to assess which template it is actually loading is to edit the header.php and adapt the line for the `<body>`

```
<body <?php body_class() ?> >
```

this way it will tell you exactly what template item it is trying to use to show the page that you are on, inside the classes of the page.